# In python, Can an abstract class be instantiated?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract, abc

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Example(ABC):
    def smile(self):
        print("smile")
```

My understanding is that `Example` becomes an `AbstractClass` when it inherits the `ABC` `class`. An `AbstractClass` can't be instantiated but
the following code executes without errors

```
example = Example()
```

Comment: Add the @abstractmethod decorator so that the class must be overridden before it is instantiated.

Comment: Are you saying `Example` isn't an `AbstractClass` until it contains an `@abstractmethod` `decorator`? what then does inheriting `ABC` do?

Comment: It does become abstract, although the methods that are contained inside are concrete. You need to make the methods inside abstract for you to not be able to instantiate it.

Comment: I've tried what would happen when there are two methods - one abstract one not - instantiating still throws an error

Answer (score 2):

Your class does become abstract, although the method/methods that are contained inside (which is `smile`) is/are concrete. You need to make the methods inside abstract using the decorator `@abc.abstractclass`. Thus, if you rewrite your code to:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Example(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def smile(self):
        print("smile")
        
e = Example()
```

then you would get the error:

```cpp
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Example with abstract methods smile
```